# Elements in a Navis works file

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

Similar to how rvt files use `[\d+]` appended to a name to indicate elements, are there any special properties or indicators that a particular node in the Autodesk-forge viewer objectTree of a nw* file is an element?

Comment: Does "rvt files use [\d+]" mean the name of the 3D object or the title of the PropertyPanel in the Forge Viewer? For example, Structure Column[123456]?

Comment: Yes! I mean eg `Structure Column[123456]`, type of string. Im not sure about Forge Viewer though, Ive only been using the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ExternalId` to indicate elements in Forge Viewer. In Revit is the `Element.UniqueId` of the Revit API as I know, but I have no idea about what this stands for in the Navisworks. You can obtain the `ExternalId` from the property object of a specific element (dbId) like this:

```
viewer.getProperties( dbId,
    function( result ) {
        console.log( result.externalId );
    },
    function( status, message, data ) {
        console.warn( status, message, data );
    });
```

And you can also retrieve dbId from a `ExternalId`:

```
viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(
    function( map ) {
        console.log( map[externalId] );
    },
    function( error ) {
        console.warn( error );
    });
```